# Slowness when submitting form

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We are seeing some fairly extreme (I would call it extreme) slowness of around 20 seconds when submitting a form on our DNN website using 2sxc forms.

The issue appears to be that on every single form submit, 2sxc executes around 20 or so SQL statements in the background, one of which takes between 8 and 13 seconds to run every single time. The rest of them take less than 100 ms. The query can be seen below.

I have tried re-indexing the DB, didn't help. I'd like to find out why this query is running and maybe how I can turn it off or do anything to increase performance.

```
    SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[EntityID] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[AttributeSetID] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[AttributeSetID1] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[ChangeID] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[EntityID1] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[EntityGUID] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll1].[AttributeSetID2] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll1].[KeyGuid] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll1].[KeyNumber] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll1].[KeyString] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll1].[IsPublished] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll1].[PublishedEntityId] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll1].[Owner] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll1].[Timestamp] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll1].[AttributeID] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll1].[AttributeID1] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll1].[ChildEntityID] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C26], 
[UnionAll1].[C10] AS [C27], 
[UnionAll1].[C11] AS [C28], 
[UnionAll1].[C12] AS [C29], 
[UnionAll1].[C13] AS [C30], 
[UnionAll1].[C14] AS [C31], 
[UnionAll1].[C15] AS [C32], 
[UnionAll1].[C16] AS [C33], 
[UnionAll1].[C17] AS [C34]
FROM  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Join3].[AttributeID1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], 
    [Project1].[AttributeSetID1] AS [AttributeSetID], 
    [Project1].[AttributeSetID1] AS [AttributeSetID1], 
    [Project1].[ChangeID] AS [ChangeID], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[EntityID] AS [EntityID1], 
    [Project1].[EntityGUID] AS [EntityGUID], 
    [Project1].[AttributeSetID] AS [AttributeSetID2], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [AssignmentObjectTypeID], 
    [Project1].[KeyGuid] AS [KeyGuid], 
    [Project1].[KeyNumber] AS [KeyNumber], 
    [Project1].[KeyString] AS [KeyString], 
    [Project1].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], 
    [Project1].[PublishedEntityId] AS [PublishedEntityId], 
    [Project1].[Owner] AS [Owner], 
    [Project1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
    [Join3].[AttributeID1] AS [AttributeID], 
    [Join3].[AttributeID1] AS [AttributeID1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join3].[AttributeID1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join3].[AttributeID2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C4], 
    [Join3].[ChildEntityID] AS [ChildEntityID], 
    [Join3].[SortOrder] AS [SortOrder], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C11], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C16], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C17]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Filter1].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], 
        [Filter1].[EntityGUID] AS [EntityGUID], 
        [Filter1].[AttributeSetID1] AS [AttributeSetID], 
        [Filter1].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [AssignmentObjectTypeID], 
        [Filter1].[KeyNumber] AS [KeyNumber], 
        [Filter1].[KeyGuid] AS [KeyGuid], 
        [Filter1].[KeyString] AS [KeyString], 
        [Filter1].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], 
        [Filter1].[PublishedEntityId] AS [PublishedEntityId], 
        [Filter1].[Owner] AS [Owner], 
        [Filter1].[AttributeSetID2] AS [AttributeSetID1], 
        [Extent3].[ChangeID] AS [ChangeID], 
        [Extent3].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], [Extent1].[EntityGUID] AS [EntityGUID], [Extent1].[AttributeSetID] AS [AttributeSetID1], [Extent1].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [AssignmentObjectTypeID], [Extent1].[KeyNumber] AS [KeyNumber], [Extent1].[KeyGuid] AS [KeyGuid], [Extent1].[KeyString] AS [KeyString], [Extent1].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], [Extent1].[PublishedEntityId] AS [PublishedEntityId], [Extent1].[ChangeLogModified] AS [ChangeLogModified], [Extent1].[Owner] AS [Owner], [Extent2].[AttributeSetID] AS [AttributeSetID2], [Extent2].[AppID] AS [AppID]
            FROM  [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_Entities] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_AttributeSets] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AttributeSetID] = [Extent2].[AttributeSetID]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[ChangeLogDeleted] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[ChangeLogDeleted] IS NULL) ) AS [Filter1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_ChangeLog] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[ChangeLogModified] = [Extent3].[ChangeID]
        WHERE ([Filter1].[AppID] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__1 <> cast(1 as bit)) ) AS [Project1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT [Distinct1].[AttributeID] AS [AttributeID1], [Extent5].[AttributeID] AS [AttributeID2], [Extent5].[ChildEntityID] AS [ChildEntityID], [Extent5].[SortOrder] AS [SortOrder]
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent4].[AttributeID] AS [AttributeID]
            FROM [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_EntityRelationships] AS [Extent4]
            WHERE [Project1].[EntityID] = [Extent4].[ParentEntityID] ) AS [Distinct1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_EntityRelationships] AS [Extent5] ON ([Project1].[EntityID] = [Extent5].[ParentEntityID]) AND ([Distinct1].[AttributeID] = [Extent5].[AttributeID]) ) AS [Join3]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2 AS [C1], 
    [Project4].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], 
    [Project4].[AttributeSetID1] AS [AttributeSetID], 
    [Project4].[AttributeSetID1] AS [AttributeSetID1], 
    [Project4].[ChangeID] AS [ChangeID], 
    [Project4].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Project4].[EntityID] AS [EntityID1], 
    [Project4].[EntityGUID] AS [EntityGUID], 
    [Project4].[AttributeSetID] AS [AttributeSetID2], 
    [Project4].[C1] AS [C3], 
    [Project4].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [AssignmentObjectTypeID], 
    [Project4].[KeyGuid] AS [KeyGuid], 
    [Project4].[KeyNumber] AS [KeyNumber], 
    [Project4].[KeyString] AS [KeyString], 
    [Project4].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], 
    [Project4].[PublishedEntityId] AS [PublishedEntityId], 
    [Project4].[Owner] AS [Owner], 
    [Project4].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
    [Join8].[AttributeID3] AS [AttributeID], 
    [Join8].[AttributeID3] AS [AttributeID1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join8].[ValueID1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C9], 
    [Join8].[ChangeLogCreated] AS [ChangeLogCreated], 
    [Join8].[ValueID1] AS [ValueID], 
    [Join8].[ValueID1] AS [ValueID1], 
    [Join8].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Join8].[ChangeLogCreated] AS [ChangeLogCreated1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join8].[ValueID1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join8].[ValueID2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C10], 
    [Join8].[DimensionID1] AS [DimensionID], 
    [Join8].[DimensionID1] AS [DimensionID1], 
    [Join8].[ReadOnly] AS [ReadOnly], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join8].[ValueID1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join8].[ValueID2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE LOWER([Join8].[ExternalKey]) END AS [C11]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Filter4].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], 
        [Filter4].[EntityGUID] AS [EntityGUID], 
        [Filter4].[AttributeSetID3] AS [AttributeSetID], 
        [Filter4].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [AssignmentObjectTypeID], 
        [Filter4].[KeyNumber] AS [KeyNumber], 
        [Filter4].[KeyGuid] AS [KeyGuid], 
        [Filter4].[KeyString] AS [KeyString], 
        [Filter4].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], 
        [Filter4].[PublishedEntityId] AS [PublishedEntityId], 
        [Filter4].[Owner] AS [Owner], 
        [Filter4].[AttributeSetID4] AS [AttributeSetID1], 
        [Extent8].[ChangeID] AS [ChangeID], 
        [Extent8].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent6].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], [Extent6].[EntityGUID] AS [EntityGUID], [Extent6].[AttributeSetID] AS [AttributeSetID3], [Extent6].[AssignmentObjectTypeID] AS [AssignmentObjectTypeID], [Extent6].[KeyNumber] AS [KeyNumber], [Extent6].[KeyGuid] AS [KeyGuid], [Extent6].[KeyString] AS [KeyString], [Extent6].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], [Extent6].[PublishedEntityId] AS [PublishedEntityId], [Extent6].[ChangeLogModified] AS [ChangeLogModified], [Extent6].[Owner] AS [Owner], [Extent7].[AttributeSetID] AS [AttributeSetID4], [Extent7].[AppID] AS [AppID]
            FROM  [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_Entities] AS [Extent6]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_AttributeSets] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[AttributeSetID] = [Extent7].[AttributeSetID
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do, but specifically 2sxc 9.30 is much, much much faster at saving, because it does a partial cache-update only.

Otherwise rebuilding your indexes on your DB usually also helps a lot.

Comment: Yep. I had the same issue.  We rebuilt indexes and all is well.  Now we rebuild indexes monthly.